# 188852525225 is shown as 1.89E+11 in CSV format report

Tags: csv, jasper-reports, ireport

I am working with ireport having field telephone number. It works fine with all formats of the report but in CSV format it prints 1.89E+11. I can change it using cell formatter in Excel.

I want to know if we can make any change in text field property so that it can display the number properly in CSV format without making changes in cell formatter of excel as well?

Comment: Did you check the file with a text viewer (Notepad or Notepad++)? The [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file contains only data, it does not contain any information about how to show data (formatting rules). This is issue of MS Excel.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. Yes you are absolutely right. I have checked it in notepad++.. It looks fine.. This issue is with MS Excel.. I asked this question just to ensure if there is any way..